# How many strings of 4 letters do NOT have "x" in them?

Tags: combinatorics

I've been pondering this problem for a while and after searching around here, I've found plenty of ways to show how many strings of $4$ letters do have "x", but I can't seem to find the opposite.

I've narrowed my answers down to $26 \cdot 26 \cdot 26 \cdot 26 - 1$ or $26 \cdot 26 \cdot 26 \cdot 26$ and even then, I'm unsure as to if I'm the right track or not.

Forgot to state that repetition IS allowed and only lowercase is considered.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

We have $25$ choices for each letter (no "$x$" allowed), so there are $$25\cdot 25\cdot 25\cdot 25=25^4=\color\green {390\ 625}$$ possible strings.

Comment: I apologize, I forgot to point out that repetition is allowed and only lowercase is considered. I don't know if that changes the result, but I wanted to make sure

Comment: Repitition is considered. Lowercase means $26$ possible letters, right ? Is "$x$" fobidden or "$X$" ? If it is "$X$", we still have $26$ choices.

Comment: Yes, it's simply "x" and the question simply asks me to determine how many 4 letter strings does not have x. Sorry, I'm only 2 weeks into discrete math and it's quite difficult to understand

Comment: @JeremyJackson The opposite by the way is "at least one $x$" , not just "one $x$" because this could be interpreted as "exactly one $x$", which is NOT the opposite.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Very much appreciated